# How do I manage multiple ubuntuone accounts?

Tags: accounts

I have 2 ubuntuone accounts. I am logged it to the first I created, and my ubuntu natty pc folders are synced with that account.

I want to switch my ubuntu pc to the second account, but I can't find the way. If I disconnect from the first account, the client should give me the possibility to choose another account; on the contrary, I can't see any way to change the account data.

Am I blind?

Comment: Service is obsolete

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. Ubuntu One is much more than just a file storage thing. It potentially contains your databases, bookmarks, contacts, application configurations, web identities, etc. It doens't make much sense to use more than one Ubuntu One account. Does it? If it does, then you should provide a use case scenario and maybe it'll become possible in the future.

Comment: my scenario is that I have various groups of friends, and

Comment: You don't log onto other peoples accounts in order to share with them. You can share a folder with your friends by providing the email address they used to register the u1 account. You can choose if they should be able to edit or not. Works very similarly to Windows filesharing, except via the internet.